# mapping boolean columns to a categorical equivalent in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```py
data = \
{'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'A': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'B': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 'C': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 'D': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 'E': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

So I want to create a new column, `class` that takes a `0` if A is true (`A=1`), a `1` if B is true (`B=1`), a `2` if C is true, and so on.

Expected output:

```py
   id   A   B   C   D   E class
0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   2   0   0   0   1   0   3
2   3   0   1   0   0   0   1
3   4   0   0   0   0   1   4
4   5   0   0   1   0   0   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), which returns a tuple with the indices of the elements that are non-zero, and select the second element.

```
df['class'] = np.nonzero(df.iloc[:,1:].to_numpy())[1]

print(df)

   id  A  B  C  D  E  class
0   1  1  0  0  0  0      0
1   2  0  0  0  1  0      3
2   3  0  1  0  0  0      1
3   4  0  0  0  0  1      4
4   5  0  0  1  0  0      2
```

Or [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and avoid the need for [`df.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html).

```
np.where(df.iloc[:,1:].eq(1))[1]
```

Comment: Yeah, I go with the  `np.where...` option.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['class'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.B+x.C*2+x.D*3+x.E*4, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id  A  B  C  D  E  class
0   1  1  0  0  0  0      0
1   2  0  0  0  1  0      3
2   3  0  1  0  0  0      1
3   4  0  0  0  0  1      4
4   5  0  0  1  0  0      2
```